# How to deploy react application in a shared hosting and how to deal with the env variables stored in .env

Tags: reactjs, deployment, environment-variables, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy a react application in a shared hosting, but I am wondering how to deal with the env variables I stored in .env file.
Such as api url for axios call etc.
Should i create a .env file after building the react application?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to create .env file after create a react app and

You need to write .env with the REACT_APP prefix like

```
REACT_APP_BASEURL = 'url'
```

You can access them this code

```
process.env.REACT_APP_BASEURL
```

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: After builiding i mean not creating the application

Comment: If you have .env file and you create a build of it. Then it should automatically pick your .env file.

Comment: What happens if i want to change the env file?

Comment: Then just update the value of variable in .env file manually.